# Converting decrypt function from VB to JS

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a function coded in vb. I am trying to convert it to Javascript

VB

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim Total As String
    Dim Tmp As String
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Tmp = Mid(s, i, 1)
        Tmp = Asc(Tmp) - 15
        Tmp = Chr(Tmp)
        Total = Total & Tmp
    Next i
    Decrypt = Total
End Function
```

So far this is what I have

```
function decrypt( s ) {
  let tmp = ''
  let total = ''

  for ( let i = 1; i < s.length; i ++) {
    tmp = s.substring(i, 1)
    tmp = tmp.charCodeAt(0) - 15
    tmp = String.fromCharCode(tmp)
    total += total + tmp
  }
  return total
}
```

Im getting the error `RangeError: Invalid string length` at line `total += total + tmp`

How can I fix this function please

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `total += total + tmp`? This is exponential string size in the length of `s`, you add itself to itself, and something extra. I don't know VB, but it doesn't look like that version does that either. You probably meant `total = total + tmp` or `total += tmp`, but not both.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I changed the += to = 
Its returning the wrong value still. I think there is something else wrong

Comment: At least it's not crashing anymore ;) as mentioned, i don't know VB, and there is no explanation for how the function is supposed to work, so I only mentioned in a comment, what i found suspicious.

Comment: @Will could you please provide an example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exact translation. Tested in excel VBA.

```js
function decrypt(s) {
  var total = ""
  for (var i = 1; i <= s.length; i++) {
    var tmp = s.substring(i - 1, i);
    total += String.fromCharCode(tmp.charCodeAt(0) - 15);
  }
  return total
}

console.log(decrypt("hello"))
```